# Criteria queries in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, criteria

Is there Hibernate criteria like queries in JPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA 2.0 has it. Refer [1] from OpenJPA.

[1] http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/manual/jpa_overview_criteria.html

Answer (score 4):

As said above it exists but i don't really like it.
You should read that blog article which tell you how to use JPA Criteria with Spring-Data or Querydsl:
http://blog.springsource.org/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: I agree. Criteria queries is one of the JPA 2 features I don't use. At least not directly.

Comment: So true. The criteria api from jpa is not well designed. the article about the specification pattern shows better ways of implementing type safe queries. I wonder why this is not something the "expert group" could come up with...#